# Angular momentum of child and swing system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum

when a child is riding a swing the angular velocity of the swing with respect to the point of suspension keeps on increasing (given that, the child is keep on swinging by his own).
Who is providing external torque in this situation?
Why the angular momentum of the swing + child system is not constant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you get a playground to swing from stationary?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/117038/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of the swing as an oscillator you can add a force to drive the oscillator, and if the driving force is near the resonance frequency then the amplitude of the oscillator will grow.

So a child rocking back and forth on the swing is using their own energy to change their center of gravity and its position with respect the lines holding the seat. So the moment of inertia of the swing and child is not constant as the swing moves. One way to model that in a paper by [Case and Swanson](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.16477) [image]
[image]

If you work out the equations you can find that at least for small angles it is like a driven oscillator driven at $\omega$, while for larger amplitudes it can be driven like like a parametric oscillator at frequency $2\omega$.

There are other ways to drive the swing, instead of leaning back and forth, a kid can just straighten their knees out a the appropriate frequency, or a more extreme case could crouch and stand in the swing. In the second case, it would be more like a parametric oscillator since if the swing was at rest, standing up and down would not start the motion. There would need to be some initial oscillation.

So shifting the center of mass (using the internal energy of the child) is adding energy from the gravitational field to the system at the right times. Or by rotating the legs with a kick adding to the angular momentum at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity introduces external moment, once you managed to move the centre of gravity from the vertical projection of the hinge of the swing.

And you can move the centre of gravity, relying on the reaction of the hinge as an external force

*More to come if needed*