How does one start swinging on a swing/hammock?
Let's say Alice is sitting on a swing/hammock, in its rest position. In order to start swinging, she moves her body in the way everyone knows how to do, to start swinging. From a conservation of energy standpoint, I get that she is transfering the chemical energy in her body into motion of her arms, into kinetic energy of the hammock. However, from a conservation of center of mass point of view. The Alice + hammock system is closed (more on this assumption later) so any push Alice does forward should push the hammock backwards and thus create no net motion.
I suspect that the points at which the hammock is attached to whatever support system is holding it, are actually secretly open boundary conditions of some sort that makes the system not closed. But I'm not sure I understand how this works.
I'd like an explanation of:

How does the start of a swinging motion from rest doesn't violate conservation of center of mass.
What's physically the mechanism that transfers energy from Alice to Kinetic energy of the hammock? Is it some time evolution of the multipole mass momenta of the Alice + hammock system? How is it actually done?


This question is similar to: Oscillate a swing without touching the ground. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/117038/2451 and links therein.
